# Query returning current connection details in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic11g

My Java EE application is pointing to an unknown Oracle database and I need to check from the application the database host name, its SID, current user and connection port.

I have no access to the database connection details because my application uses a data-source provided by the application server (Weblogic 11g) and I have no access to its admin console. I have the application's source and I can deploy and debug a new version of it in the server.

How can I get the current database user, database host and service from the current connection?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a query using [SYS_CONTEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions172.htm#SQLRF06117) function.

- To get the server's host:

  ```
  SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') FROM dual
  ```
- To get the current schema:

  ```
  SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') FROM dual
  ```

Comment: Plus: to get the current user, use `select user from dual`